# new! and create! in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Please anyone tell me why we use `new!` or `create!` in rails controller?

Example==>

```
def new
  new! do |format|
  format.html {
  set_group_and_class_autocomplete_data_sources(@node)
  }
 end
end

def create
  create! do |success, failure|
  failure.html {
  set_group_and_class_autocomplete_data_sources(@node)
  render :new
  }
 end
end
```

Comment: Could you find where `new!` and `create!` are defined ? They don't exist in the standard rails codebase. Maybe in a parent class of your controller ? In a gem ?

Comment: I believe the exclamation point methods are custom made (didn't come with rails3) but usually they throw an exception while the methods without the exclamation point usually return false upon error. They can also appear when something irreversible is done inside the method.

Answer (score 1):

The create!, update_attributes! are methods that raises exceptions if the record is invalid.

Check this out:

[Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-first_or_create-21)